# Tildes in a jQuery selector appears to return length === 0

Tags: jquery

I have inputs on a form, some of which have tildes in them.  Example:

id is "ctl00_MiddleContent_CTR1_gvCT_ctl02_txtCTSTATUS279~2~0"

If I use it in a jQuery selector (I am using jQ 1.8.3):

```
var id = "ctl00_MiddleContent_CTR1_gvCT_ctl02_txtCTSTATUS279~2~0";
var sr = $("#" + id);
```

In this case, sr.length === 0

Why is the tilde problematic?

A solution: I solved my problem by escaping them using \ as in:

```
var sr = $("#" + id.replace(/\~/g, "\\\~"));
```

Now sr.length === 1 but I still would like know why tildes are problematic in my case here.

Comment: It's described here: https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/